# Android app unknown new Localizations

Tags: android, localization, apk

I am trying to update my android game on Play Store. Just after uploading the apk, Play Store says there are three new languages were found in localizations section and I do not know where they came from.

How can I remove them? (I am on Mac OS X 10.9.1, using eclipse kepler & ADT 22.3)

This is how it looks like in Play Store.

[image: ps]

This is how my res folder looks like. I do not have values-es or values-iw.

[image: res]

Comment: Maybe your project depends on some other project which has es & iw values set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was because the newly added facebook sdk. Removing values-es, values-iw etc. folders from facebook-sdk project solved the problem.